# Creating a NuGet package programmatically

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I am trying to create a basic NuGet package programmatically using [Nuget.core API](https://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest).

Firstly I populate Metadata and Files field of NuSpec manifest file:

```
Manifest nuspec = new Manifest(); //creating a nuspec

ManifestMetadata metaDataLocal = new ManifestMetadata()
{
    Authors = "mauvo",
    Version = "1.0.0.0",
    Id = "myPackageIdentifier",
    Description = "A description",
};

nuspec.Metadata = metaDataLocal; //populating nuspec's metadata

ManifestFile mf = new ManifestFile();
mf.Source = "bin\\Debug\\DX11VideoRenderer.dll";
mf.Target = "lib";

List<ManifestFile> listManifestFile = new List<ManifestFile>();

listManifestFile.Add(mf);
nuspec.Files = listManifestFile; //populating nuspec's Files field
```

Then I use package builder class to create the package and save it to the debug folder of my project:

```
PackageBuilder builder = new PackageBuilder() 
{
    Id = "1",
    Description = "Some test package"
};

builder.Populate(nuspec.Metadata);

foreach (ManifestFile value in nuspec.Files)
{
    builder.PopulateFiles(value.Target, nuspec.Files);
    builder.Files.Add(new PhysicalPackageFile()
    {
        SourcePath = value.Target,
        TargetPath = @"lib\" 
    });
}

using (FileStream stream = File.Open("bin\\Debug", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    builder.Save(stream);
}
```

I have hardcoded all the source paths, destination path, package info and metadata. But for some reason the package is not being created. Code runs without any errors.

Comment: Is is problem solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess it is probably being saved, but the file's name is `Debug` rather than `x.nupkg`.

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Open("bin\\Debug", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    builder.Save(stream);
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry but that's not the problem. I tried both debug and dubug/a.nupkg